# Which folder should the classes file be for a JSP to access it?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, classpath

In what folder do you need to keep your class files for a JSP to access them if you are using Netbeans IDE?

Comment: Okay i will do that.I just understood what that means.Sorry i dont use stackoverflow a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is the `WEB-INF/classes` folder in your WAR file.

Comment: I would ask where applets were mentioned; JSPs are explicitly called for.  And of course they need to be in the directory structure as defined by packages.  The compiler will create them that way.  NetBeans ought to be compiling the .class files and moving them into an exploded WAR file.